# Certificação OCA Java 8, existe em português? Onde devo pagar a prova e em que instituição fazer?

Tags: java, java-8

Boa Tarde meus companheiros.

Tenho interesse em fazer a prova de certificação JAVA 8, OCA, só que não falo em inglês, existe prova em português, se existe onde eu devo efetuar o pagamento e em que instituições do RJ eu devo fazer contato para marcar a prova?

Caso seja em inglês, alguém que fez, sabe se pode usar o translate do navegador na hora da prova?

Eu estudo pelo livro da casa do código e alguns cursos da alura, vocês conhecem mais algum conteúdo bom para ajudar na hora da prova.

Muito obrigado a todos !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo aos seus questionamentos:

- Não é possível fazer o exame em português. É possível fazer apenas em inglês, japonês ou espanhol
- Não pode usar nenhuma ferramenta no momento da prova. Nem tradutor, nem nada. Lhe é fornecido apenas uma espécie de lousa física para rascunho
- Você pode escolher algum centro para fazer a prova ou pode fazer em casa (respeitando alguns termos e condições)
- Você pode agendar seu exame (bem como o local) pelo site da [Pearson VUE](https://home.pearsonvue.com/)
- [Esse livro](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCA-Java-SE-Estudos-1Z0-808/dp/8582604769/ref=sr_1_fkmrnull_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1YVGUH5VGIQUI&keywords=oca%20java%20se%208%20guia%20de%20estudos%20para%20o%20exame%201z0-808&qid=1557516786&s=gateway&sprefix=oca%2Caps%2C252&sr=8-1-fkmrnull) é um bom material de estudo